# How to select id's that ONLY have the value of n

Tags: mysql

I have a table of student course completions, which includes all the grades that students have claimed from their courses. The grades are paired with student ID's and I need to select the students who have ONLY achieved 3 as their grade in any of their courses.

My first and ( at the time of writings ) my last intuition would be to write the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM table
WHERE grade = 3;
```

However it returns all the students who had 3 as their grade and not only those who have only had 3's as their grades.

I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to go about this. Perhaps the simplest to read is

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM table 
WHERE grade = 3
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE grade <> 3);
```

This gets everyone that has a 3 and does not have any non-3's.

There might be other more efficient approaches. To know which is the most efficient approach, profiling (explaining, analyzing, ...) can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could groupy by the ID and check the sum of grades that weren't 3. This works because in MySQL Boolean expressions evaluate to 0 when false and 1 when true.

```
SELECT id
       FROM table
       GROUP BY id
       HAVING sum(grade <> 3) = 0;
```